# How to protect against CSRF by default in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, csrf-protection

Inspired by: [How to protect against CSRF by default in ASP.NET MVC 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965342/how-to-protect-against-csrf-by-default-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Is there a way to achieve the same result in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery

Comment: @MU So if I were to add this globally, simply adding `services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute()));` would be enough?

Comment: @Ludisposed Yes, that will automatically enforce CSRF validation on all routes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply `AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute` as a global filter in `Startup.ConfigureServices()`, so it applies to all of your routes automatically:

```
services.AddMvc(options => 
    options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute()));
```

Note that `AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute` only applies to unsafe requests (POST, PUT), not safe ones (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE). This way, the antiforgery token is only required for actions that are susceptible to CSRF attacks. It's important to make sure only your POST or PUT actions modify data!

This global filter approach is recommend by the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery#autovalidateantiforgerytoken) for non-API applications.

Comment: So I don't even need to `Ignore` the GET's?

Comment: @Ludisposed With `AutoValidate` you don't need to use `IgnoreAntiforgeryToken` on GET routes. That's the "auto" part. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to protect from CSRF for good is not using cookies for authentication at all. If that is a possibility I would try checking token authentication and implement it. No cookie, no CSRF.

As far as I know it's not a big deal to have JWT token auth e.g. with Core.

Comment: One of the problems with tokens (in a non-API context) is storing them safely. Cookies are vulnerable to CSRF, but they at least have the HttpOnly flag. Storing stuff in localStorage doesn't have that safety measure. See this discussion: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/148163/110474

Comment: Yes, I know, but you have to first execute something like XSS to read them. It's not like anyone can just do it, but it's of course a valid concern. Also if you have ability to read from local storage you can probably just call any webapi you want anyway, cookie will be sent automatically.